# How can I close a file handle while function exit with exception in Python?

Tags: python

For instance, I have a function like:

```
def example():
    fp = open('example.txt','w+')
    fp.write(str(1/0))
    fp.close()
```

Then it will throw an exception because 1/0 is not defined. However, I can neither remove `example.txt` nor modify `example.txt`. But I have some important data in Python, so that I can't simply kill Python and run it again.

How could I finish opening the file when the function finish with an exception.

**What shall we do if we didn't place a try:.. except:.. ?**

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('example.txt','w+') as fp:
    try:
        fp.write(...)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print('there was an error: {}'.format(e))
```

Using the `with` context manager any files opened by it will be closed automatically once they go out of scope.

Comment: Does it means that if we didn't place a `try...except...`, we can no longer close the file?

Comment: No, you can still use open and close the same way as before the context manager just makes sure the file stays open as long as you need it and closes it once you are done with it. [Read more here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap that in a try/except to handle the error and close the file reader before the program ends.

```
def example():
    fp = open('example.txt', 'w+')
    try:
        fp.write(str(1/0))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        fp.close()
    fp.close()
```

Edit: The answer by @IanAuld is better than mine. It would be best to accept that one.

Comment: Actually my question is, if I didn't write a try...except... structure, can I close the file?